# Echo something when no rows are found in SQL While loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop that goes through all rows in an sql database. inside of the loop I print the content of the row, however when the query returns 0 rows, no code inside that loop is executed. How can I make it run some code when no rows are found?

Example:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");
while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
     if (empty($row1)) {
          echo "Nothing found";
     } else {
           echo "Found something";
      }
}
```

Problem I'm having is that when the while returns nothing, the if isn't executed at all.

Edit: I'm aware I should use mysqli or similar

Comment: As [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) say: _Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows._ Because you have no rows to start with the loop never runs. Best to check if you have some rows first.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @Tom Don't worry. I'm aware. My boss doesn't want to hear it though, because 'it works' and 'this is what he\'s used to'

Comment: @Qbyte Tell your boss he needs to look into this stuff if he wants to keep doing what he is doing for much longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should stop using `mysql_` functions, as they are depricated, and start using `mysqli_` functions, `MySQLi` class or `PDO`.

To answer your question there is the `mysql_num_rows` function which returns the number of rows returned by the statement:

```
$stmt = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");
if (!mysql_num_rows($stmt)) {
    echo "Nothing found";
} else {
    while (/*...*/) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I had tried something similar but I put the num_rows inside of the while loop which obviously doesn't work. I don't have time to try this right away but I'm pretty sure it will do the trick so I will accept this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");
if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) === 0) {
      echo "Nothing found";
} else {
    while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        echo "Found something";
    } 
}
```

it will echo "Found something" multiple times though, one time for each row. if you don't want it like this you have to move this outside the while loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that your loop is not executed at all if no result is returned.

Consider using an explicit flag instead, that makes the code much easier to read:

```
<?php
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");

$resultWasEmpty = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $resultWasEmpty = false;
    // do whatever you want to do with $row
} 

if ($resultWasEmpty) {
    echo "Nothing found";
}
```

Alternatively you can simply use the function returning the number of rows in the result set: `mysql_num_rows($qry)`...

---

Apart from that a general *warning*:

You are using the old, outdated and deprecated `mysql` extension. You should really switch to the current `mysqli` extension or the `PDO` package.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_num_rows` function.

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");
if( mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0 ) {
    while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        // do something with the record
    }
} else {
    // no record found in database
}
```

P.S. `mysql_*` extension is no longer supported in PHP 7. You should consider using `mysqli_*` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT .......etc");
if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0){
   while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
      echo " found";
   } 
}else{ 
   echo "Nothing found";
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer so the OP understands what you did and why